# Nuxt 3 route middleware does not run on server

Tags: middleware, nuxtjs3

I'm working on an authentication guard in Nuxt 3 that I would like to implement with router middleware. Unfortunately, I can't get this router middleware to run on the server, meaning that the client renders a page that's supposed to be guarded before redirecting.

To make sure that this isn't caused by any asynchronous authentication processes, I created a middleware that should always redirect when server rendered.

`middleware/auth.ts`

```js
const test = "1234";

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(() => {
  // const user = useSupabaseUser();

  if (test === "1234" && process.server) {
    return navigateTo("/login");
  }
});
```

`pages/profile.vue`

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Button } from "flowbite-vue";

definePageMeta({
  middleware: "auth",
});

const supabase = useSupabaseClient();
const user = useSupabaseUser();
</script>

<template>
  <Header type="default" class="mb-8"> View your profile </Header>
  <Paragraph>Email: {{ user?.email }}</Paragraph>
  <Paragraph>Id: {{ user?.id }}</Paragraph>
  <Paragraph>Phone: {{ user?.phone }}</Paragraph>
  <Paragraph>Role: {{ user?.role }}</Paragraph>
  <Button @click.prevent="() => supabase.auth.signOut()">Log out</Button>
</template>
```

`nuxt.config.ts`

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: ["@nuxtjs/tailwindcss", "@nuxtjs/supabase"],
  components: ["~/components"]
});
```

This middleware will never redirect to the login page when navigating to the profile page, even though I would expect it to always redirect. The guarded page should be invisible client-sided. The server should return a HTTP redirect.

Does anyone know how to make this run on the server?

Kind regards,
Jelle

Comment: Did you try to actually use it in your route component? As far as I see, it will work unless you are not using it.

Comment: Yes I use it in my page component. This example does redirect as soon as the client loads the guarded page if I remove the `process.server` check.

Comment: Edit question and show how you use it. Together with `nuxt.config` settings.

Comment: Edited my question. The nuxt.config doesn't include a whole lot of settings because I use the default folder names to include middleware, components and pages.

Comment: So everything is working fine like it should be. The guarded page should be visible to a client, or they won't be able to download it. If you want to have that kind of guarding abilities, change your framework to Laravel in PHP. There's no any authentication going on server side. Vue 3 framework is just SSR rendered, so users can crawl your website and paste results in chats/posts.

Comment: I don't care about clients crawling the page, but I would expect the route middleware to be server rendered also, so it sends the correct page or redirect right away. The Nuxt docs also state that route middleware should be server-rendered.

Comment: @DutchJelly Did you ever find out what's going on here. My middleware doesn't log anything in the server either. I have no idea what the people above are talking about. This behavior doesn't makes sense.